# For,if,elif loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

So my Problem is I have a list with number or strings d=[3050,1964,1250] Depending on the name 3050,1964 or 1250 the code needs to pick the right list. List [500,500,500,500,500,500] if 3050 or List [500,500,500,400] if 1964 or list [400,400,400] if 1250.

It also has to append/compile all the list togehter as sublist. So the Resulst would look like e=[[500,500,500,500,500,500],[500,500,500,400],[400,400,400]]

I have tried to wright a code below but it dose not work and I dont understand what to do. Please help

```
d=[3050,1964,1250]
e=[]
for i in d:
  if i==3050:
    calc=[500,500,500,500,500,500]
  elif i==1964:
    calc=[500,500,500,400]
  else: 
    calc=[400,400,400]
    e.append(calc)
```

Comment: The e.append is only getting called in the else condition, i.e. for `i == 1250`. But this seems like an awful lot of unnecessary code to just say `e=[[500,500,500,500,500,500],[500,500,500,400],[400,400,400]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
d=[3050,1964,1250]
e=[]
for i in d:
  if i==3050:
    calc=[500,500,500,500,500,500]
  elif i==1964:
    calc=[500,500,500,400]
  else: 
    calc=[400,400,400]
  e.append(calc)
```

You got the last line wrong, it doesn't align with the function above

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem try this:

```py
d=[3050,1964,1250]
e=[]
for i in d:
  calc=[400,400,400]
  if i==3050:
    calc=[500,500,500,500,500,500]
  elif i==1964:
    calc=[500,500,500,400]
  e.append(calc)
```